# CsvHelper: Replace missing Csv field with another expression?

Tags: c#, automapper, csvhelper

When a field is missing in the CSV file, an exception is thrown. I'd rather map another value (such as empty string) when a field is missing.

```
Map(dest => dest.PatientID).Name("Patient ID");

CsvHelper.CsvMissingFieldException: 'Fields 'Patient ID' do not exist in the CSV file.'
```

If the configuration setting IgnoreReadingExceptions is used, no records are read into the results.

```
var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
csv.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
records = csv.GetRecords<TR>().ToList();
```

How can I change the mapping such that when the mapped field is MISSING, it can be replaced with another expression?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 2.x you can do this:

```
csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
```

In 3.x you can do this:

```
// Turn off.
csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;


// Log missing field.
csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = ( headerNames, index, context ) =>
{
    logger.WriteLine( $"Field with names ['{string.Join( "', '", headerNames )}'] at index '{index}' was not found. ");
};
```

Comment: Is there any update to that? How to do it in ver. 30.x ?
All I need is to set values to null if column is missing, preferably without defining a custom ClassMap.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions the CsvReader Configuration is read only for example this no longer works:

```
csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
```

You can set that in the config prior

such as 30.x you can use something like this:

```
var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    MissingFieldFound = args => { 
        logger.WriteLine( $"Field with names ['{string.Join( "', '", args.HeaderNames)}'] at index '{args.Index}' was not found. ");
        //do something with (args.Index, args.HeaderNames,args.Context. 
    }
};
```

or nothing

```
var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    MissingFieldFound = () => { }
};
```

Then use the config:

```
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, config))
```