# CSVHelper mapping not picking up when column is missing

Tags: csvhelper

I've been using the CSVHelper and I must say that it is absolutely fantastic. I'm having an issue though with the mapping when the column is not in the file.

```cs
using (var stream = client.GetDownloadStream(string.Format("{0}{1}", _remoteFileDirectoryExports, remoteFileName)))
{
    using (var s = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(s, new Configuration()
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            HeaderValidated = null,
            MissingFieldFound = null
        });

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EverTrueInteractionMap>();

        records = new List<T>();

        foreach (var r in csv.GetRecords<T>())
        {
            records.Add(r);
        }
    }
}
```

My mapping class is below.

```cs
public class EverTrueInteraction
{
    public string InteractionImportId { get; set; }     
    public string Solicitor1ImportId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor1EverTrueId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor1Name { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor2ImportId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor2EverTrueId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor2Name { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor3ImportId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor3EverTrueId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor3Name { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor4ImportId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor4EverTrueId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor4Name { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor5ImportId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor5EverTrueId { get; set; }
    public string Solicitor5Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class EverTrueInteractionMap : ClassMap<EverTrueInteraction>
{
    public EverTrueInteractionMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.Solicitor1ImportId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor1EverTrueId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor1Name).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor2ImportId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor2EverTrueId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor2Name).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor3ImportId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor3EverTrueId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor3Name).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor4ImportId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor4EverTrueId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor4Name).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor5ImportId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor5EverTrueId).Default("");
        Map(m => m.Solicitor5Name).Default("");
    }
}
```

When the Solicitor3 - 5 are not in the file it's returning null for their values. Will the .Default("") not work for this?

Comment: Anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that .Default() is for supplying a missing *value*, but what you have is a missing *field*.

So if you wanted to replace empty fields with "NOVALUE" then .Default() is your guy. If you want to handle an entirely missing column, you'll need to modify the Configuration.MissingFieldFound setting and/or handle it by catching the exception.

See:
[CsvHelper: Replace missing Csv field with another expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605569/csvhelper-replace-missing-csv-field-with-another-expression)

and
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/

Could you accomplish what you're after by simply setting the default value on your class attributes themselves? Just setting them to the empty string during construction?

e.g.

```
public string Solicitor3EverTrueId { get; set; } = "";
```

Comment: Defaulting the value on my class worked perfectly. Thanks Tim!